# FORALL update is updating only last record from collection and it's giving error ORA-22160: element at index [1] does not exist error message

Tags: plsqldeveloper

FORALL update is updating only last record from collection and it's giving error ORA-22160: element at index [1] does not exist. I have scenario were i have to update million of records. When i execute the below code the update is happening only for the 100th record remaining 99 records remains same( i tested with 100 records). after execution it's giving ORA-22160: element at index [1] does not exist. i am using oracle 9i database.need suggestion for this issue.

```
Declare 
 CURSOR tk_iflow_cur
  IS
    SELECT DISTINCT top.rule_id,
      top.rule_item_id,
      msib.segment2
    FROM iflow_rules top,
      iflow_active_rules msib
    WHERE top.rule_id = msib.rule_item_id
    AND msib.organization_id  = 5039 and rownum<=100
    ORDER BY top.ora_inv_item_id; -- cursor fetches 100 row 
  ---Variable declaration
TYPE l_iflow_id
IS
  TABLE OF VARCHAR2(200) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
TYPE l_iflow_org
IS
  TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
TYPE l_iflow_inv_id
IS
  TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
TYPE l_r12_inv_id
IS
  TABLE OF NUMBER;
TYPE l_r12_item_key
IS
  TABLE OF VARCHAR2(200) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
TYPE l_r12_iflow
IS
  TABLE OF VARCHAR2(200) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
TYPE l_omar_item_id
IS
  TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
TYPE l_omar_seg2
IS
  TABLE OF VARCHAR2(200) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
  tk_iflow_id l_iflow_id;
  tk_iflow_org l_iflow_org;
  tk_iflow_inv_id l_iflow_inv_id;
  t_omar_item_id l_omar_item_id;
  t_omar_seg2 l_omar_seg2;
  r12_inv_id l_r12_inv_id:=l_r12_inv_id();
  r12_item_key l_r12_item_key;
  r12_iflow l_r12_iflow;
  user_excep  EXCEPTION;
  v_err_count NUMBER;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (user_excep, -24381);
  r12_item_id2 VARCHAR2(200);


BEGIN --
  tk_iflow_id.DELETE;
  tk_iflow_inv_id.DELETE;
  OPEN tk_iflow_cur;
  LOOP --Cursor Loop
    tk_iflow_id.DELETE;
    tk_iflow_inv_id.DELETE;
    t_omar_seg2.DELETE;
    FETCH tk_iflow_cur BULK COLLECT INTO tk_iflow_id, tk_iflow_inv_id, t_omar_seg2; ---100 records assigned to variables
    FOR i IN 1..tk_iflow_id.COUNT -- to store the cursor value
    LOOP                         --for Loop
      BEGIN
        --Comment : passing the cursor value to derive new records from different instance for updating the records
        SELECT DISTINCT segment1,
          inventory_item_id,
          item_type
        INTO r12_iflow(i),
          r12_item_id2,
          r12_item_key(i)
        FROM iflow.ifl_active_rules@R12_db_link
        WHERE segment1           =tk_iflow_id(i)
        AND NVL(SEGMENT2,'NULL') = NVL(t_omar_seg2(i),'NULL')
        AND organization_id      =5063;
      EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        r12_inv_id(i)   := 0;
        r12_item_key(i) := 0;
      END;
      r12_inv_id :=l_r12_inv_id();   
      r12_inv_id.EXTEND (i);
      r12_inv_id (i) := r12_item_id2;

    END LOOP; --end for loop
    BEGIN
      FORALL i IN r12_inv_id.FIRST..r12_inv_id.LAST SAVE EXCEPTIONS -- for all the derived records i'm updating the target table.100 records i'm  updating 
      UPDATE iflow_active_rules 
      SET ora_org_id      =5063,
        ora_inv_item_id   =r12_inv_id(i)
      WHERE iflow_id       =r12_iflow(i)
      AND ora_inv_item_id = tk_iflow_inv_id(i);
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN user_excep THEN
      v_err_count := SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS.COUNT;
      FOR i       IN 1 .. v_err_count
      LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ( 'Error: ' || i || ' Array Index: ' || SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS (i).ERROR_INDEX || ' Message: ' || SQLERRM (SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS (i).ERROR_CODE) );
      END LOOP;
    END;
    BEGIN
      FORALL i IN r12_inv_id.FIRST .. r12_inv_id.LAST SAVE EXCEPTIONS
      UPDATE iflow_rules --- updating openup system iflow cost details
      SET ora_org_id      =5063,
        ora_inv_item_id   =r12_inv_id(i)
      WHERE iflow_id       =r12_iflow(i)
      AND ora_inv_item_id = tk_iflow_inv_id(i) ;
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN user_excep THEN
      v_err_count := SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS.COUNT;
      FOR i       IN 1 .. v_err_count
      LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ( 'Error: ' || i || ' Array Index: ' || SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS (i).ERROR_INDEX || ' Message: ' || SQLERRM (SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS (i).ERROR_CODE) );
      END LOOP;
    END;
    EXIT
  WHEN tk_iflow_id.COUNT=0;
    COMMIT;
  END LOOP; --End Cursor Loop
  CLOSE tk_iflow_cur;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are using `r12_iflow` collection in the scope of collection `r12_inv_id` where it not not accessible. `FORALL` statement is differnt the `FOR LOOP`. Even though they work pretty on same logic but they differs on scope of usage of variables. You can create a `RECORD` in your case and do the processing. See below how you can do it. PS Not tested.

```
DECLARE
   CURSOR tk_iflow_cur
   IS
        SELECT DISTINCT top.rule_id, top.rule_item_id, msib.segment2
          FROM iflow_rules top, iflow_active_rules msib
         WHERE     top.rule_id = msib.rule_item_id
               AND msib.organization_id = 5039
               AND ROWNUM <= 100
      ORDER BY top.ora_inv_item_id;                  -- cursor fetches 100 row


     Type var_cur is table of tk_iflow_cur%rowtype index by pls_integer;      
     l_cur   var_cur; 

     --Record of your variables.
     TYPE var_rec is RECORD 
     (
        l_r12_iflow  VARCHAR2 (200),
        l_r12_inv_id number,
        l_r12_item_key VARCHAR2 (200)

     );

     TYPE rec is table of var_rec index by pls_integer;

     --Variable declared to hold the result of your cursor.
     l_rec   rec;

   user_excep        EXCEPTION;
   v_err_count       NUMBER;
   PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (user_excep, -24381);
   r12_item_id2      VARCHAR2 (200);
BEGIN                                                                           
   OPEN tk_iflow_cur;

   LOOP                                                          --Cursor Loop     

      FETCH tk_iflow_cur  BULK COLLECT INTO l_cur LIMIT 100; ---100 records assigned to variables        

      FOR i IN 1 .. l_cur.COUNT             -- to store the cursor value
      LOOP                                                          --for Loop
         BEGIN
            --Comment : passing the cursor value to derive new records from different instance for updating the records
            SELECT DISTINCT segment1, inventory_item_id, item_type
              INTO l_rec(i).l_r12_iflow ,l_rec(i).l_r12_inv_id ,l_rec(i).l_r12_item_key
              FROM iflow.ifl_active_rules@R12_db_link
             WHERE  segment1 = l_cur(i).rule_id
              AND NVL (SEGMENT2, 'NULL') = NVL (l_cur(i).segment2 , 'NULL')
              AND organization_id = 5063;
         EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS
            THEN
               l_rec(i).l_r12_iflow := 0; 
               l_rec(i).l_r12_inv_id:= 0; 
               l_rec(i).l_r12_item_key := '';
         END;

      END LOOP;                                                 --end for loop

      BEGIN
         FORALL i IN 1 .. l_rec.COUNT SAVE EXCEPTIONS -- for all the derived records i'm updating the target table.100 records i'm  updating
            UPDATE iflow_active_rules
               SET ora_org_id = 5063, 
                   ora_inv_item_id = l_rec(i).l_r12_inv_id
             WHERE     iflow_id = l_rec(i).l_r12_iflow 
              AND ora_inv_item_id = l_rec(i).l_r12_inv_id;

      EXCEPTION
         WHEN user_excep
         THEN
            v_err_count := SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS.COUNT;

            FOR i IN 1 .. v_err_count
            LOOP
               DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
                     'Error: '
                  || i
                  || ' Array Index: '
                  || SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS (i).ERROR_INDEX
                  || ' Message: '
                  || SQLERRM (SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS (i).ERROR_CODE));
            END LOOP;
      END;

      BEGIN
         FORALL i IN 1..l_rec.COUNT SAVE EXCEPTIONS
            UPDATE iflow_rules   --- updating openup system iflow cost details
               SET ora_org_id = 5063, 
                   ora_inv_item_id = l_rec(i).l_r12_inv_id
             WHERE     iflow_id = l_rec(i).l_r12_iflow 
             AND ora_inv_item_id = l_rec(i).l_r12_inv_id;

      EXCEPTION
         WHEN user_excep
         THEN
            v_err_count := SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS.COUNT;

            FOR i IN 1 .. v_err_count
            LOOP
               DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
                     'Error: '
                  || i
                  || ' Array Index: '
                  || SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS (i).ERROR_INDEX
                  || ' Message: '
                  || SQLERRM (SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS (i).ERROR_CODE));
            END LOOP;
      END;

      EXIT WHEN tk_iflow_cur%NOTFOUND;
    END LOOP;                                                 --End Cursor Loop

   COMMIT;
   CLOSE tk_iflow_cur;

END;
```